# Unable to access webservice with CXF client when WSDL is not available at the service URL

Tags: cxf-client

This is my first time with CXF. I am writing a client to consume a webservice. My requirement is to write a client and also add a logging interceptor. Unfortunately, the service provider does not make the `WSDL` available through a `URL?wsdl`. I have all the required `WSDLs and XSDs` from the service provider in a zip file and I have to use this version of files to build my client. I have followed several examples so far and read quite a bit about `CXF` clients. It seems like the following approach to get a client running is correct. However, it does not work here. I need help with solving this.

```
JaxWsProxyFactoryBean factory = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();
factory.setServiceClass(<SERVICE_CLASS_NAME>.class); <<I have the ".class for service here>>
QName SERVICE_NAME = new QName(<<namespaceURI>>, <<ServiceName>>);
factory.setServiceName(SERVICE_NAME);
factory.setAddress(SERVICE_URL);
factory.setWsdlLocation(localWSDLAddress);
portType = factory.create();
```

This is a standalone client program and I have tried several combinations of jar files to run this program (Details follow). The program does not run beyond the last line mentioned in the code snippet above. The exception trace is as follows.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapTransportFactory.createEndpointInfo(Lorg/apache/cxf/service/model/ServiceInfo;Lorg/apache/cxf/service/model/BindingInfo;Ljava/util/List;)Lorg/apache/cxf/service/model/EndpointInfo;
 at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceBuilder.buildEndpoint(WSDLServiceBuilder.java:459)
 at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceBuilder.buildServices(WSDLServiceBuilder.java:356)
 at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceBuilder.buildServices(WSDLServiceBuilder.java:203)
 at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceFactory.create(WSDLServiceFactory.java:175)
 at org.apache.cxf.wsdl.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromWSDL(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:408)
```

command line used for running my client program that contains the above code snippet. I have arrived at this list of jar files through trial and error.

```
java -cp %CLASSPATH%;.;./cxf-core-3.0.2.jar;./cxf-rt-bindings-soap-3.0.2.jar;./cxf-rt-bindings-xml-3.0.2.jar;./cxf-rt-core-2.7.11.jar;./cxf-rt-frontend-simple-3.0.2.jar;./cxf-rt-ws-addr-3.0.2.jar;./cxf-rt-ws-policy-3.0.2.jar;./neethi-3.0.2.jar;./wsdl4j-1.6.3.jar;./xmlschema-core-2.1.0.jar;./cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-3.0.2.jar;./cxf-bundle-3.0.0-milestone2.jar;./cxf-bundle-jaxrs-2.7.12.jar;./woodstox-core-asl-4.4.1.jar;./stax2-api-3.1.4.jar;./cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb-3.0.2.jar;./cxf-common-utilities-2.5.11.jar;./cxf-rt-transports-http-3.0.2.jar javaclass
```

Answer (score 0):

Include the WSDL as part of your project and generate java code of the client / server.

Use the cxf maven plugin for generating the code:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-sources</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated/cxf</sourceRoot>
                <wsdlOptions>
                    <wsdlOption>
                        <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/ws/booking-v1.wsdl</wsdl>
                        <wsdlLocation>classpath:ws/booking-v1.wsdl</wsdlLocation>
                        <bindingFiles>
                            <bindingFile>${basedir}/src/main/resources/bindings.xml</bindingFile>
                        </bindingFiles>
                    </wsdlOption>
                </wsdlOptions>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```